# How do you express that you have a twin sister?

Tags: english-to-japanese

How do you say “I have a twin (older) sister”? I am still unsure how to introduce my twin.

Comment: Just say that you two are Sausages.

Answer (score 1):

私は双子の姉がいます - "I have a twin (older) sister."

twin - 双子

older sister - 姉

If you're introducing her you could say something like, こちらは双子の姉です